# How to rename folders and files recursively in MacOS

Tags: macos, bash, recursion, rename

I used to have a Debian machine and I remember using something like:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename 's/changethis/tothis/' **
```

But maybe because my bash version (version 3.2.48(1)) is not up to date I get:

```
-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
-bash: rename: command not found
```

What would be different way to recursively rename files and folders in OS X? (10.8.5)

---

I want to rename every folder and file that have the string `sunshine` in it to `sunset`. so the file:
`post_thumbnails_sunshine` will become `post_thumbnails_sunset` and `r_sunshine-new` will become `r_sunset-new` etc.

Comment: For one, `rename` seems to be a third-party utility: http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/. (Available on Homebrew.) And `globstar` is new in Bash 4.0: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option

Comment: You'd want to use straight-up unix commands at the command prompt. Something like: `find . -name "from_this" -exec mv {} to_this \;`

Comment: @mbratch this will only replace exact matches.. I want to also rename file such as `changethis-one` to `tothis-one`

Comment: I'm not following. Your new replacement example doesn't show any wildcards, nor does the example in your problem statement. Can you explain further in your problem description what you're trying to rename? Do you have a list of what to rename? Or a pattern?

Comment: @mbratch added pattern to the question.

Comment: You may be able to add globstar following this: http://mistermorris.com/blog/get-yourself-globstar-bash-4-for-your-mac-terminal/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 find . -depth -name "*from_stuff*" -execdir sh -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/from_stuff/to_stuff/")' \;
```

Comment: you should avoid using backticks. `$()` it's better.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for spotting that, I agree (edited).

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
find . -name '*sunshine*' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f//sunshine/sunset}"; done
```

*to specifically rename only files use `-type f`, for directories use `-type d`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression in the `find` command as stated @mbratch in the comments. You could use `-regex`, `-iregex` and `-regextype` to provide a complete expression to `find`. Then invoke `-exec mv {} +` (note the `+` sign).